# Emojis not working and special character unicode not recognised

Tags: c#, emoji

My program can't seem to recognize my emojis, and the Unicode escape code I got from [a Unicode code converter](https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/) (1F510 for ) isn't recognized by visual studio (Unicode escape codes normally turn purple, but for this one, all the symbols turned purple, except for the last one).

```
Console.WriteLine("/A- G comme groupe");
Console.WriteLine("/B- J comme Jeu de sons");
Console.WriteLine("/X- L comme Liré");
```

Could someone help me figure it out?

Comment: The code compiles and runs. Please explain exactly what the problem is that you have with it, and/or what you mean by "aren't recognized by visual studio".

Comment: Yeah, I did it, sorry

Answer (score 0):

To use a unicode character such as your emoji you can do the below:

```
Rune d = new Rune(0x1F512);
```

Where 0x1F512 is the hex vale for the emoji you want. Note this is only available in .NET core 3.0 and higher.

This explains the topic more in depth:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding-introduction